# How can I clear the server-side MVC model validation errors from a bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "list of clients" page with an "add" button that pops up a bootstrap modal, allowing the user to enter details of a new client.

The body of the modal is generated by a partial view, which is rendered as part of the "list" page initially.

When the user clicks add, the form is submitted to the server via an AJAX call. If there are model errors, then the server will respond by re-sending just the body of the modal (with validation errors), which on the client side is injected back into the modal.

I'm using `@Html.ValidationSummary()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in the usual way to add the model errors.

If the user now clicks "cancel", and then later clicks the "add" button again, the modal re-appears. In this case, I want to treat it as a fresh start and clear all the validation errors from the body of the modal. I know how to clear the client-side ("unobtrusive") validation errors, but how can I clear the errors added by `@Html.ValidationSummary()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`.

I could go back to the server and ask it to re-render with a fresh model, but I guess I'm looking for a shortcut that doesn't involve another AJAX call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$.fn.clearErrors = function () {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).find(".field-validation-error").empty();
        $(this).trigger('reset.unobtrusiveValidation');
    });
};
```

if you think it is difficult understand, the below code has the same effect:

```
function resetValidation() {
        //Removes validation from input-fields
        $('.input-validation-error').addClass('input-validation-valid');
        $('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        //Removes validation message after input-fields
        $('.field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid');
        $('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error');
        //Removes validation summary 
        $('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
        $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');

    }
```

Comment: Thanks - sounds good. Can you confirm how the first one should be invoked?